# Trying to automate timestamps for GoogleSheets with AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I went through documentation and thought my code would work but it doesn't. It actually seems to do anything which confuses me greatly.

```
function onEdit() 
{
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) //check we are on sheet1
  { 
    var r = s.getActiveCell(); // create variable of active cell
    if( r.getColumn() == "C" ) //check if the cell being edited is in column C
    { 
      var prevCell = r.offset(0, -1); // goes one cell to the left
      if( prevCell.getValue() === '' ) // checks if cell is empty
      { 
        prevCell.setValue(new Date_Time()); //populates cell with date and time
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me out

The idea is that if I type anything on any cell in column C it should populate the date+time on the cell to the left.

Comment: Welcome. You've got two outstanding answers! There's a lot for you to take in but please take the time to learn about [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). They provide a lot of information about the edit (or whatever trigger you have used). You can always insert `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) ` into your script to find the actual event objects available to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 3) {
    if (e.range.offset(0, -1).getValue() === '') {
      e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date()); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `s.getName()` is the Spreadsheet title. By this, when your sheets in the Google Spreadsheet don't include the same sheet name with the Spreadsheet title, `if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" )` is always `false`. I thought that this might be the 1st issue of your script.
- `r.getColumn()` returns the column number like `1, 2, 3,,,`. So, `if( r.getColumn() == "C" )` is always `false`. I thought that this might be the 2nd issue of your script.
- Unfortunately, I cannot know your script of `new Date_Time()`. But, if you want to just put the date, `new Date()` can be used.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, your script is modified.

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if (r.getColumn() == 3) {
      var prevCell = r.offset(0, -1);
      if (prevCell.getValue() === '') {
        prevCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification,the event object is used.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var { range } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && range.columnStart == 3) {
    var prevCell = range.offset(0, -1);
    if (prevCell.isBlank()) {
      prevCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

- For both modified scripts, when a value is put to column "C" of "Shee1", the date object is put to column "B" of the same row.
- About "Modified script 2", this is run with the event object. So, when you directly run the script, an error like `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.` occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [getName() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getname)
- [getSheetName() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetname)
- [getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn)
- [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)
- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)